# Getting Mapbox contours to show up

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to add the contours layer from Terrain v2 to my style, but I can't get anything to show up. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It's my top layer and I chose 'line' for type. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LWrI.png)

Comment: I believe the terrain data is only available between zoom levels 9-15. Are you looking within this range?

Comment: Thank you, yes, this was my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please details what you have done so far?

You can follow these steps to move layers from one style to another

1. Go to the map style that has the styled layers
2. Select the styled layer you want to copy
3. Click the  to access the JSON editor
4. Copy the JSON text
5. Go to the new style you want to add these layers
6. Add the layer you want to style by clicking +Add Layer
7. Select the newly added layer and go to the JSON Editor (see Step 3 to see how)
8. Delete what's in the JSON editor
9. Paste what you copied from Step 4 into the JSON editor